# PHP get class by name (but case insensitive)

Tags: php

I know we can instantiate class Foo() by doing new $Foo, how would I do the same case insensitively?

ie. Instantiate Foo() by new $foo()
ie. Instantiate /FolderName/FBIAgent() with new $foldername\fbiagent()

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to do this?

Comment: I think it's OS specific - Windows allows case insensitive search of files (and class names too), while using Linux server there will be error if cases does not match!

Comment: What is `/FolderName/FBIAgent`?

Comment: The answer would be "don't do it". Find differen way of solving your problem.

Comment: The actual simple answer is that you should ALWAYS assume that EVERYTHING is case sensitive.  Uppercase characters ARE different than lowercase.  So you should never take the chance that some intermediate process will automatically resolve the characters.  It was a bad practice that Windows ever allowed that to begin with.

Comment: "Instantiate /FolderName/FBIAgent() " : please rephrase, one cannot instantiate a function. Please also format your code (use backticks). Mixing code and natural language is hard to read without proper formatting. Anyways, the answer is probably "No".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class names in PHP are case insensitive. However, when autoloading gets mixed in, that property may be lost.

A simple solution if you expect a limited set of classes is to pre-load them all, making sure the symbols are defined at the time you dynamically instanciate the objects.

If you do not know all possibilities at the time of loading, you could work around the issue using a custom autoloader. Class map autoloaders typically map the exact class name to a file path. If you lowercase all file names in the keys and lowercase the class name before the lookup, you would have a case insensitive autoloader.

Comment: [phpab](https://github.com/theseer/Autoload) for instance provides a PHP-compliant autoloading mechanism.